# Import declaration conflicts when using Strophe.MUC

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, strophe, strophe.js

I had a working project using StropheJs and its typings file. 
When I tried to add the MUC typings file I'm getting the following errors:

1. Namespace 'Strophe' has no exported member 'Connection'
2. Namespace 'Strophe' has no exported member 'Status'.
3. error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Strophe'

The error seems to be in the index.d.ts typings file for Strophe.

```
import Strophe = wrapper.Strophe;
```

The error seems to be a conflict in the naming of the namespaces and I can't solve it. I want to change the index.d.ts file to import this correctly but I don't know how to do it.

In [this article](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/trying-to-make-strophe-js-dance-to-the-ionic-tune/67349/2) they mentioned that they had to change the index.d.ts file to make this work.

Any input is appreciated.

The index.d.ts and the muc.d.ts definitions can be installed via npm and also available [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/strophe)

> npm install --save @types/strophe

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I am also getting the issue.

Comment: I did not. I ended up using Strophe as type 'any'.